# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freenect'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, kinect

I installed libfreenect using a [tutorial](https://naman5.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/experimenting-with-kinect-using-opencv-python-and-open-kinect-libfreenect/)

At the end, it had me run the program by typing python kinect_test.py into the terminal on Ubuntu. This runs the program without errors. However, when I open the same file through Pycharm and run it, I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freenect'`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling libfreenect, but the error is still there and the file continues to run fine when started in the terminal. I am fairly new to linux and python and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your Pycharm project is most likely configured to use a virtual environment that was created when you created the project. Checl your pycharm settings to make sure that your project interpreter is the same one that is used when you run the python script from the terminal